# Magento 2.3 get custom category attribute in .phtml file

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I have created a custom category attribute `title_description` and is showing on the admin side and I can save data. But when I try to show the value on the frontend using `getTitleDescription()` it is not showing anything. It is working for default category attributes like `getName()` and `getId()`. In my block I have created the function

```
public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        $currentCategory = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
        return $currentCategory;
    }
```

And in .phtml file I am calling

```
$block->getCurrentCategory()->getTitleDescription()
```

It works on other pages where I am using a collection of categories and looping through it. But not working when calling an individual category

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95563/magento-2-how-to-get-custom-category-attribute-on-frontend I hope this will help you!
Thanks

Comment: Couldn't find any accepted answer there!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try adding

```
public function getTitleDesc()
{            
    return $this->getCustomAttribute('title_description');            
}
```

In your block and then call the function.
Note you should flush the cache before calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom attribute to Magento's list of attributes that it'll load by default when loading categories.

Create a file called `catalog_attributes.xml` in the `etc` folder of your module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="catalog_category">
        <attribute name="title_description"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

Note that the group is called `catalog_category`, which is the group for auto-loaded attributes. This file is capable of doing other things as well, which you can learn about [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/317840/5694).